# MT3620, I2C(ISU2) on M4F fails in ARM-Release

Tags: c

Writing a bare metal application (not using FreeRTOS) for the M4F core on MT3620 using the I2C (ISU2) to write/read data from a INA260 device. Using M4_Software from Mediatek-Labs Git OS_HAL)

Everything works when running in ARM-Debug (either Start without debug or with debug). When building application as a ARM-Release the I2C interface fails to write to slave device:

Init:

```
result = mtk_os_hal_i2c_ctrl_init(i2c_master_port_num);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("I2C CTRL Init Failed!\r\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("I2C CTRL Init OK: %d!\r\n", result);
    }
    result = mtk_os_hal_i2c_speed_init(i2c_master_port_num, i2c_master_speed);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("I2C Speed init Failed!\r\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("I2C Speed Init OK: %d!\r\n", result);
    }
    result = ina260_readManufacturerIdRegister();
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("INA260 not initialized! Err: %d\r\n", result);
    }
    else {
        printf("I2C Speed Init OK: %d!\r\n", result);
    }
```

Init Ina260:

```
int ina260_readManufacturerIdRegister(void) {
    uint16_t value = 0; 
    
    ret = ina260_readRegister(MANUFACTURER_ID_REGISTER, &value);
    if (value != 0x5449) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Write/Read from Ina260:

```
...
static uint8_t intInaBuffer[2] = { 0 };
    
    ret = I2C_OK;
    
    
    intInaBuffer[0] = reg;
    ret = mtk_os_hal_i2c_write(i2c_master_port_num, INA260_ADDR, intInaBuffer, 1);
    if (ret != I2C_OK) {// Failed 
        printf("ina260_readRegister: I2C Write failed: %d\n", ret);
        goto ina260_end;
    }
...
```

Output on UART (debug):

```
I2C CTRL Init OK: 0!
I2C Speed Init OK: 0!
ina260_readRegister: I2C Write failed: 146
INA260 not initialized! Err: 1
ina260_readRegister: I2C Write failed: 146
ina260_readVoltage: I2C Write failed: 146
```

Environment settings:
AzureSphereTargetApiSet": "5+Beta2004"
Your device is running Azure Sphere OS version 20.06.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks so much for any input! :)

Regards
Brian

Comment: Who/what is printing `INA260 not initialized! Err: 1` and what does `1` mean? And, what does the `146` return mean? Why does the "not initialized" message appear _after_ the first `I2C Write failed` message? Please _edit_ your post and provide this info and post your `ina260` initialization code. As it is, it appears that device specific initialization is not being done correctly.

Comment: I don't know about your particular OS/environment, but, what about the "unitialized data" section for globals (e.g. `int x;`). Most environments will [statically] initialize these to zero and it's the same for debug/production mode. Under WinX [and _not_ POSIX], however, it will initialize to zero for production mode, but, under debug mode, WinX will put [and I disagree with the rationale] a non-zero value there (e.g. `0xE5`?) to catch "unitialized values". If there was any code like `int *ptr;` and then: `if (ptr == NULL) do_init();` this might break. What does your build doc say about this?

Comment: `mtk_os_hal_i2c_speed_init` it does not look bare metal for me. You use magic HAL libraries

Comment: The init function is simply comparing the vendor ID of the chip when trying to read from it. Edit post with this function. I have other I2C slaves on the bus and they also fails on read/write. I have looked through the docs to find the 146 return code without any luck.